# Which arduino should I start on to learn about it?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm pretty interested in arduino and the things I can learn from it. Being that I'm new into this I wanted to know which model I should get that would be easiest to learn on and why. What does this model come with, how much, and reputable place where one can purchase this.

Comment: How new are you? Do you know EE? C++?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! This question is really broad since we don't know anything about your abilities and skills. For now, I've closed the question. You can edit your question to add more information (i.e. programming skill, needs/wants, budget, potential projects, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply say: buy a [startkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MO9L5WC) like this one.At the end it is not important which Arduino board you'll start. They are (almost) the same*. At the very beginning you can start with [Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) or [Nano](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano) and even [Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) could be very good. Those boards are very similar and you can program them in the same. Even the pins location and designation is not really different.
The most important thing about Arduino is to understand how to work and program and interface such a board with the sensors. In this sense I would choose a Uno board (or even 2009) which is less expensive and very easy to find overall. I don't really know how much experience you have, but it is likely, at the beginning, that you invert polarities of batteries, you drain too much power, or you invert some pins and damage the microcontroller. In that case doesn't make sense to buy the last powerful mega expensive board on the mark. If you get a Uno you can do almost everything and have for the next month a lot to learn.

To change from Uno or Nano to the other board it is not very difficult. Once you understand the basis you can switch to every board you want. If you need more power and memory you can buy a Mega. If you need much more power you can buy a Due/Tre/etc...you need just an *upgrade* not everything from scratch to learn.

If you are really new to Arduino the best way is to buy such a learn package as I showed you above. That have everything you need to understand basic of programming till to RC-Servo movement and motor drivers.

Happy new year.

*: stay away for the moment from the Arduino Due/Tre/Zero/Yuan/.. series. they are too expansive and require a lot of attention (3.3V, max drain current from the pins, pull up, pull down...etc..). Here is the risk to get your board damaged within few time very high. And you'll spend a lot of time thinking that the board has some problems.

Comment: Not to mention that most of those are ARM-based and so will require relearning the in-depth stuff if you go there.

Comment: Agree on the starter kit. Another option if you don't know much/any programming or electronics is start with a makeymakey board.  The main thing is to learn basic electronics and interfacing and to get comfortable breaking down things into small basic steps that are easy to program.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you are right but seen from the side of the program doesn't too much from Due und Uno. There are new functions, of course, but the IDE and all the library stuff is the same. But in EE you are right, it needs a lot more caution and deep understanding how microcontroller works

Comment: It's best to buy an official starter kit: you support the community and you receive support if something doesn't work as expected http://store.arduino.cc/product/K000007